# When you see a post with 9 votes

Tags: discussion, fun

... do you upvote it so they get a badge?

Sometimes I do...

Comment: Sorry... I'm bored... so sue me

Comment: Can I interest you in a few posts... :-P

Comment: There, enjoy your new badge :)

Comment: damn, forgot to wikifi and got 2 downvotes

Comment: If Id get a badge evertime my answer didn't get critical mass...

Comment: Badges? We don't need not stickin'... oh shiny

Comment: A bell rings everytime someone gets a 'Nice Answer' badge.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sometimes if I see a particularly good answer — something worth voting for twice if I could — I'll check that user's profile and look for another *deserving* answer with 9 votes, so I can "give" them a badge.

The most recent case was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007340/javascript-function-aliasing-doesnt-seem-to-work/1162192#1162192), because it really advanced my understanding of javascript, but I couldn't find a 9-vote post for that user.

Comment: Not a bad idea.

Comment: There, I gave him a badge for you.

Answer (score 28):

Not if it sucks.

Comment: But if it got 9 votes it must not suck

Comment: Ah, Juan... your sunny optimism brightens my day. ;-)

Answer (score 16):

I don't care if 9 other people think it's good. I upvote when *I* think it's good.

Answer (score 5):

I always do.  It feels good to hand out badges.

Answer (score 3):

I usually try to disregard the current total as best I can and vote based on the merit of the answer alone.

Sometimes I wonder if the 10-vote threshold is intimidating to people, since a number of my answers tend to asymptote to around +9. They get a quick surge of votes and then just stagnate.

Maybe they should make a new badge: The "So close" badge for when you have an answer that is stuck at +9 for a few months. ;)

Comment: Even better if it was the first answer and was accepted. I've got a couple of those.